# Efficient method to compute inverse of R stacked matrices

Tags: matlab

I have the following input:

- `R` matrices `S_1,...,S_R` all of which are `n-by-n` and invertible.  These are stored in the cell-array `S{r}`, `r=1,...,R`.
- `R` matrices`x_1,...,x_R` all of which are `n-by-k`.   These are stored in the cell-array `x{r}`, `r=1,...,R`

I require the following output:

- A `(n*R)-by-k` matrix `B` with entries `B = (S_1\x_1,...,S_R\x_R)`.

One way to compute this is via a `forloop`:

```
% Preallocate resources
B = zeros(n*R,k);
% Loop:
for rr= 1:R
     B( (rr-1)*n + 1: (rr-1)*n + n,:) =  S{rr}\x{rr};
end
```

This there a more efficient way of carrying out this computation.  In particular, is there a way to avoid the `forloop`?

Comment: Just in case: you know that `\ ` is **not** matrix division, right?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I made the title (hopefully) more clear to reflect this.

Comment: Since you already have all the matrices stored in a cell, you could use `cellfun`: `B=cellfun(@(a,b) a\b,S,x,'UniformOutput',0)'; B=cat(1,B{:});`, but you would still be doing a kind of for in the back of cellfun...

Comment: @ana Thanks, I will try this.  I could also organize output so that it is a stacked matrix `S = [S_{1} ; ... ; S_{R}]`,  if it is possible to perform some sort of operation that does not require a `forloop`.